# What's the significance of the zoom parameter in the DroneDeploy Tiles API?

Tags: web-applications, dronedeploy

I'm creating a DroneDeploy app to allow users to save a DroneDeploy tile URL schema (`https://public-tiles.dronedeploy.com/1492897911_ADMININSPIRE_ortho_iti/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?Policy=a&Signature=b&Key-Pair-Id=c`) for use in other applications. I see that the [Tiles API](https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/tiles.html) accepts a `zoom` parameter. As far as I can tell the URL schema I get in return doesn't change if I change the zoom parameter, so I'm just wondering what the purpose of this parameter is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past we used the zoom parameter in the tile API to return an array of tiles at the given zoom level. We've decided later to move that iterator into a separate iterator function [found here.](https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/tiles/example-tiles-as-array.html)

So in answer to your question, the `zoom` parameter does not do anything. The tile API only returns the tile template. I've opened up a PR on our side to remove the zoom parameter and will update the docs as soon as that gets merged.

Hope that helps.